# Focus Accordian Header on Collapse

Tags: jquery, focus, accordion

I have a stack of accordian in the middle of the page , i have implemented the collapse button inside the accordian content div , so that user wont have to go to top and collapse.but when i click on the button it is moving to the top instead of the accordian section.

Here is the fiddler of what i am facing right now.
http://jsfiddle.net/FKZtn/15/

```
$('#close').click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({active: false}).click();
});
```

how can i focus the header , when i click on the external collapse button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i guess you donot need to write any extra code. just change the html mark up like this for close button.put "#." instead of "#" you will be all set good.

```
 <div id="close"><a href="#.">Close</a>
```

ofcourse working fiddle

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srahel007/F5pG4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in click event:

```
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#accordion').offset().top
}, 500);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FKZtn/17/)**